# Ionic Google Maps - MapType not assignable

Tags: google-maps, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

Weird observation with the Ionic/Cordova Google Maps. I want to bring up the map with `hybrid` maps.

```js
if(!this.map){
      // const myMapType: MapType = 'HYBRID';
      const mapOptions: GoogleMapOptions = {
      //   controls: {
      //     compass: false,
      //     myLocation: true,
      //     myLocationButton: false,
      //     mapToolbar: false,
      //   },
      //   mapType: myMapType
      };
      this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', mapOptions);
      this.map.setMapTypeId(GoogleMapsMapTypeId.HYBRID);
}
```

Fails running with `Argument of type 'string' not assignable to parameter of type 'MapType'.` When I disable that line, the app starts. However, a second edit to enable `setMapTypeId` with `ionic livereload` loads the map in hybrid. I do not get it. Am I not preloading something that's set in the initial load and then prevails in the simulator memory so that the second time the error is not triggered?

Running simulator with 
`ionic cordova run ios --consolelogs --target "iPhone-8"`

Answer (score 0):

Should work.

```
import { GoogleMaps, GoogleMap, GoogleMapsMapTypeId} from '@ionic-native/google-maps';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-set-map-type-id',
  templateUrl: 'set-map-type-id.html',
})
export class ExamplePage {

  map: GoogleMap;

  constructor() {}

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.loadMap();
  }
  loadMap() {
    this.map = GoogleMaps.create('map_canvas', {
      mapType: GoogleMapsMapTypeId.HYBRID
    });

  }

}
```